# Add row value to arraycollection

Tags: php

After I retrieved mysql result from db, I wish to add row number value '1' '2' '3' etc to each results[].

```
if($products)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($products)){
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you'd like to start the array keys from 1, you could use a counter variable:

```
$counter = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($products) {
  $results[$counter] = $row;
  $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($products)) {
  $results[] = $row;
}
```

will key each result starting from 0 so if you do:

```
foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
  // $k = 0, 1, 2, ...
}
```

You can explicitly set the key instead:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($products)) {
  $results[$i++] = $row;
}
```

or you can add that number to the row itself if you wish:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($products)) {
  $row['row_number'] = $i++;
  $results[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to both of you for the tips, using your code and modify, I got it work within my Flex application.

```
$row[] = $i++;
```